# bootstrap 4 navbar collapsed div is moving all the header menu when is activated

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been working with bootstrap 4 migrating from 3.x And Everything is working right now, except one issue I have with the header, I have a collapsed div, for the search, which one when being activated moves all the menu and is not a very nice experience for the user (Please ignore the ugly borders in the screenshots, they are for debugging purposes only).

This is the normal Menu

[image: Normal Menu]

And when I click on the search Icon

[image: Click on Search Icon]

I have another Div with the search form

[image: Search Form]

And if we look closely we can see the size of the previous div is bigger, and all the items were moved to the left

[image: Bigger Space and moved to the left]

UPDATE:

here is an animated gif of the issue:

https://i.gyazo.com/a19328136dea86aebf6566972d7855e5.mp4

Here is the Gist with the HTML layout code: https://gist.github.com/ricardojriosr/1aa3f0c77c4d6786b42cce6d03a9c154

How Can I fix this, so the menu doesn't change the size and move to the left the items? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Im not sure I understand the issue. I cant see a "bigger" space and I cant see where items have moved

Comment: Where's the code that toggles the div?

Comment: @Emily7687687 Hi, I added a gif of the issue https://i.gyazo.com/a19328136dea86aebf6566972d7855e5.mp4

Comment: @ZimSystem here is all the code of the nav, the last div is the collapsed div https://gist.github.com/ricardojriosr/1aa3f0c77c4d6786b42cce6d03a9c154

Comment: Ohh. I think this is a transition issue. In your CSS, do you have .collapsing ?

Comment: @Emily7687687 not at all, Double checked now

Comment: Could be an issue related to all the Grid columns you're using without any `.row` to provide proper positioning. Or that you're changing Grid behavior from the default (flex) to inline at various points.

Comment: @RobertC I think I didn't get What you meant

Comment: You're applying the Bootstrap Grid to your navigation; generally this requires you to use `.row` as a wrapper for proper positioning.

Comment: Can you set a codepen or similar with the navbar?, would be easier for everyone to test

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding

```
.collapsing {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height .35s ease;
}
```

in your CSS.

Comment: Thank you, but it has the same behavior

Comment: The best way to figure out whats going on is to debug. right click on the element in Google Chrome, click on 'inspect' and find the element. On the right look at the styles controlling it. Click on the icon and watch the styles change. This will reveal the issue

Comment: You dont see a difference between the element before, during and after transition?

Comment: Just a class, but I checked that class and is not affecting the size